# WP posts_per_page & offset skipping first post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a simple ajax call to load 3 posts on my WordPress website, everytime when clicked the first 3 results always skip the first post in the database.

The Ajax is set on page 0, and adds 3 posts per page. So I expect the output to be the first 3 posts, however it skips the first post and outputs the next 3. It will then work correctly from there on.

Why would is skip the first result on when on page 0?

**Ajax Call -**

```
var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
var page = 0; // What page we are on.
var ppp = 3; // Post per page

$("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When Load More Button is pressed.
  event.preventDefault();

    $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
    $.post(ajaxUrl, {
        action:"more_post_ajax",
        offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
        ppp: ppp
    }).success(function(posts){
        page++;
        if(posts === '') {
          $("#more_posts").hide();
        } else {
          $(".showroom-loop").append(posts); // Which div to insert the posts
        }
        $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
    });
});
```

**This is my wp args function -**

```
function more_post_ajax(){
     $offset = $_POST["offset"];
     $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
     header("Content-Type: text/html");

     $args = array(
             'post_type' => 'showroom',
             'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
             'offset' => $offset,
     );
     $loop = new WP_Query($args);

            while ($loop->have_posts()) {
                $loop->the_post();
                    echo "<h3>";the_title();echo "</h3> <hr>";
            }
            exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because your code is always adding 1 to the offset.

In your javascript, shouldn't this:

```
offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
```

be

```
offset: (page * ppp),
```